# Can't make scrapy crawl

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm attempting to understand how Scrapy works, but can't figure out how to make it crawl.

The website that i wish to crawl has a page http://www.example.com/Jason that contains links in the format http://www.example.com/Jason:Aron , http://www.example.com/Jason:Dan_De etc.

I managed to crawl the text on a page like http://www.example.com/Jason:Aron but i can't make it to start from http://www.example.com/Jason and crawl all the pages that are linked there.

This is my spider:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from tutorial.items import Item

class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "text"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.example.com/Jason",
        "http://www.example.com/Jason:Aron",
    ]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('Jason:*')), callback='parse'),)

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="textbox"]')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = Item()
            item['text'] = site.xpath('text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Notice that `Jason:*` is a regular expression (matches `Jason`, `Jason:`, `Jason::`, ...). Does it what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `CrawlSpider`, you'd better not override the [`parse()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.Rule) method:

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic. So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer work.

Change `callback="parse"` to `callback="parse_item"`, and try again.

Comment: Damn i so missed that. changing `callback="parse"` to `callback="parse_item"` and `def parse(self, response):` to `def parse_item(self, response):` made it work perfect. Thank you.